# Separating static web pages from WAR file

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache, web, tomcat

I have a web application which is a WAR file. I will be hosting this in Amazon cloud, using Linux and Tomcat. However I now need to create a different UI using HTML and CSS, no Java or WAR. My plan is, user will access this static user interface first and from a link there, they will access the actual java based web application.

There are 2 ways I can do this. First is to put all of this static content into the WAR file. Second is seprating the static content from the WAR file. I prefer the second method, because I can add info to the user interfaces without shutting down the entire web application.

But, how can I do this? How can I put these static files to tomcat and link the WAR file to it? Specially is this is possible in amazon cloud?

Comment: What server side components do you use?

Comment: @ChetanKinger: sorry, didn't get your point.

Comment: You said you have web application which is a `WAR` file. You said the static pages will access the actual java based web application. A java based web application will use server side components such as `Servlets` or `JSP`. What do you use as server side components?

Answer (score 1):

Build a java based rest api, use angular on the front end and access the rest endpoints via ajax.

Separate the two projects, upload the static html/javascript to a cdn/cache.

Or alternatively you can keep the html/javascript in the same war in the root of your webapp, it will (probably) be cached by the webserver.

Don't use JSP's.

Comment: Have you tried your answer? Do you know how much complexity it adds?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is done by providing Apache or other proxy before container. So it will forward some requests to application container, but static files by its own.